# Removing missing data from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this (experimental data):

```
{{0.04, 22.4, 43.286, 99.998}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.288, 99.997}, {0.04,22.4, 43.289, 99.997}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, {588.24, "", "",76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, {},{0.05, 22.4, 43.293, 99.997}}
```

I want to remove every sublist that has a missing value, so if a sublist is like `{588.24, "", "", 76.519}`, it should be removed, it is like `{}`, it should be removed. Can this be done in a simple way?

Comment: Try: Map[If[MemberQ[#, ""] || # == {}, Nothing, #] &, data, 1]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to remove every sublist that has a missing value

There are at least 10 ways to do this in Mathematica. One way could be

```
data = {{0.04, 22.4, 43.286, 99.998}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.288, 
   99.997}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.289, 99.997}, {588.24, "", "", 
   76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 
   76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 
   76.519}, {}, {0.05, 22.4, 43.293, 99.997}}

DeleteCases[data, x_ /; Or[MemberQ[x, ""], Length[x] == 0]]
```

gives

```
{{0.04, 22.4, 43.286, 99.998}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.288, 99.997}, {0.04, 
  22.4, 43.289, 99.997}, {0.05, 22.4, 43.293, 99.997}}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can match the data you need

```
data = {{0.04, 22.4, 43.286, 99.998}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.288, 
    99.997}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.289, 99.997}, {588.24, "", "", 
    76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 
    76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 
    76.519}, {}, {0.05, 22.4, 43.293, 99.997}};
data // Cases[{_Real ..}]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Pick[data, FreeQ[#, ""] & /@ data] /. {} -> Nothing
```

OR

```
pos = Position[data, x_ /; Length[x] > 0 && FreeQ[x, ""]]
Extract[pos][data]
```

---

Result:

> ```
> {{0.04, 22.4, 43.286, 99.998}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.288, 99.997}, {0.04, 
>   22.4, 43.289, 99.997}, {0.05, 22.4, 43.293, 99.997}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is as follows:

```
DeleteCases[Map[If[NumericQ[#] === True, #, Nothing] &, data, {-1}], {}]

(*{{0.04, 22.4, 43.286, 99.998}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.288, 99.997}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.289, 99.997}, {588.24, 76.519}, {588.24, 76.519}, {588.24, 76.519}, {588.24, 76.519}, {588.24, 76.519}, {0.05, 22.4, 43.293, 99.997}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{0.04, 22.4, 43.286, 99.998}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.288, 99.997}, 
   {0.04, 22.4, 43.289, 99.997}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, 
   {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, 
   {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, {588.24, "", "", 76.519}, 
   {}, {0.05, 22.4, 43.293, 99.997}};
```

Three more solutions / modifications

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {{___, "", ___} | {}}]
```

Using `DeleteCases` with `OrderlessPatternSequence`

```
DeleteCases[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[__, ""]} | {}]
```

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[list, {__?NumberQ}]
```

All produce

> {{0.04, 22.4, 43.286, 99.998}, {0.04, 22.4, 43.288, 99.997}, {0.04,
> 22.4, 43.289, 99.997}, {0.05, 22.4, 43.293, 99.997}}